# Unclassifiable statement when using NINT intrinsic

Tags: integer, fortran, classification

I have a simple code:

```
program test
implicit none

integer*4 nxProjPad, cf

nxProjPad=185

cf = NINT nxProjPad/2

end
```

Why when I compile it, it shows an error in the terminal:

```
Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

and the "1" points to cf.

Comment: `cf = NINT(nxProjPad/2)`

Comment: @Jim Hewitt: this way it shows: ''‘a’ argument of ‘nint’ intrinsic at (1) must be REAL'' and 1 points to "("

Comment: Youbmust divide by `2.` not `2`

Comment: 185 / 2 = 92.5, so the use of "nearest integer" function (92 ? or 93?) may need some caution... (gfortran gives 93 on my computer).

Comment: @roygvib: `185/2` should give `92` on your computer -- integer division truncates and will be performed before the result is passed to `nint` (which is not, strictly, defined on integer arguments and should cause an error).  Perhaps you meant to write `185/2.` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, yes, I meant 185 / 2.0 (sorry!). We need to be very careful about integer rounding... (one of my colleagues also had bugs with this before).

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic function `nint` rounds a `real` calling argument to the nearest whole number. Your argument is the wrong data type.

You can either declare `nxProjPad` as `real` or change your calling argument to `nxProjPad/2.0`

In the first case it is safe to assign integers to floating point numbers without losing any accuracy (but one must be careful about integer division, e.g. 1/2 is equal to 0 and not 0.5). In the second case, as long as one of the `/` operands is a float, a floating point division will be used.

WARNING: In the case where you require 64-bit precision (double precision) you have to decorate your constants with a kind suffix.

Comment: This answer misses the point, the compiler can't parse the expression `NINT nxProjPad/2` because it's missing the parentheses necessary for a well-formed function call; that would require `NINT(nxProjPad/2)`.